# Wrong exit value from pthread_exit

Tags: linux, glibc, pthread-join

Below code simply creates two threads and tries to get return values of them.

I've compiled and run it on a 32-bit glibc-2.15 system and all went right (output: r1: 1, r2: 2). However when I did same thing on a 64-bit glibc-2.17 system, output was wrong (output: r1: 0, r2: 2). Why the same code behaves differently on different systems?

Note: If types of r1 and r2 are changed to `void*` or `int*` as commented below, code works on both systems.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

void* worker(void* arg) {
    int i = (int) arg;
    pthread_exit((void*)i);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    pthread_t tid[2];
    int err = 0;
    err = pthread_create(&tid[0], NULL, worker, (void*) 1);
    if(err != 0) printf("error: %s\n", strerror(err));
    err = pthread_create(&tid[1], NULL, worker, (void*) 2);
    if(err != 0) printf("error: %s\n", strerror(err));

    ///*
    int r1 = 0, r2 = 0; // <-- WRONG: r1: 0, r2: 2
    //void *r1, *r2; // <-- OK: r1: 1, r2: 2
    pthread_join(tid[0], (void**) &r1);
    pthread_join(tid[1], (void**) &r2);
    printf("r1: %d, r2: %d\n", (int) r1, (int) r2);
    //*/

    // make comment above snippet and uncomment below snippet: // <-- OK: r1: 1, r2: 2 
    /*
    int *r1 = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
    int *r2 = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
    pthread_join(tid[0], (void**) r1);
    pthread_join(tid[1], (void**) r2);
    printf("r1: %d, r2: %d\n", (int)(*r1), (int)(*r2));
    */
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: on a 64-bit system, `sizeof(void*) != sizeof(int)`, and by passing `&int` into `pthread_join` you are invoking undefined behavior (and corrupting stack; running that variant of the program under Address Sanitizer should detect the error).

In the case where you pass `&int`, but the `int` was heap-allocated, you are corrupting heap instead, but you don't notice that yet (your program is likely to crash later on subsequent `malloc` or `free`). Running that variant of the program under Valgrind or Address Sanitizer should trivially prove heap corruption to you.

Longer answer: `pthread_join(tid, &x)` essentially performs this:

```
memcpy(&x, previosly_used_pthread_exit_value, sizeof(void*));
```

It should now be clear that passing in address of any variable for which `sizeof(x) < sizeof(void*)` invokes undefined behavior.